# .NET saving to DB truncates my decimals instead of rounds them.. what could be possible problems?

Tags: .net, vb.net, enterprise-library

I'm not using the entity framework, but I am using the Microsoft Enterprise Library.

I have a value like: `1.125979843654984` that gets truncated to `1.125`, instead of rounded to `1.126`.

The precision of the column this value is in is Decimal(5,3).

What are some reasons that this could happen?

Is there any other information I could provide to help?

I'm new to .NET.

### Update 1

- Add relevant code

The code that invokes the saving process:

```
Dim dsCalcGroupByBand As New DataSet
dsCalcGroupByBand.Tables.Add(dtCalcGroupByBand)
dsCalcGroupByBand.Tables(0).TableName = "Table"
Dal.SaveGridDataSet(dsCalcGroupByBand, "Select * from tblLTDCalcGroupByBand where iGroupKY=" & GroupData.GroupNo, False, False)
```

The method method in the variable `Dal`:

```
Public Function SaveGridDataSet(ByVal pDS As DataSet, ByVal pSQL As String, _
    Optional ByVal pCheckIsNewGroup As Boolean = True, _
    Optional ByVal pForceAsNewGroup As Boolean = False, _
    Optional ByVal pSQLDelete As String = "") As Boolean

  Dim DA As New SqlDataAdapter
  Dim commandBuilder As SqlCommandBuilder
  Dim adapter As SqlDataAdapter
  Dim updatedRows As Integer

  Using connection As SqlConnection = _database.CreateConnection()

    Try
      If ((pCheckIsNewGroup = True) And (GroupData.isNewGroup = True)) Or _
      (pForceAsNewGroup = True) Then
        pDS = IsNewGroup(pDS)
      End If
      DA = New SqlDataAdapter(pSQL, connection) '_database.GetDataAdapter
      ' Make the CommandBuilder generate the insert, update, and delete commands.
      commandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(DA)

      ' Save the changes.
      DA.Update(pDS)

    Catch e As InvalidOperationException
      Try
        ' it's horrible to run code, in here, but there need to be tests
        ' implemented before modifying the above code.
        adapter = New SqlDataAdapter(pSQL, connection)
        commandBuilder = New SqlCommandBuilder(adapter)
        'adapter.SelectCommand = commandBuilder.GetUpdateCommand
        updatedRows = adapter.Update(pDS)
      Catch ee As DBConcurrencyException
        ' there was no change (data already exists, no need to update)
        Console.WriteLine("no data written")
      End Try

    Catch e As DBConcurrencyException

      ' Delete the current records using the optional delete pSQLDelete
      If pSQLDelete = "" Then
        pSQLDelete = pSQL.Replace("Select *", "Delete")
      End If
      UpdateSQL(pSQLDelete)

      ' Now Create the dataset as if a new group and try the update again
      DA.Update(IsNewGroup(pDS))
    Catch e As Exception

      Console.WriteLine("Un-mitigated exception")
      Console.WriteLine(e.Message)
    End Try


  End Using


End Function
```

- Disclaimer to the above code snippets: They both came from legacy code.

Using the above decimals for an example:
in the `dtCalcGroupByBand` `DataTable`, there exists a row a field of value `1.125979843654984` corresponding to a column in the database of datatype Decimal(5,3) -- however, the particular corresponding DataColumn object is of datatype `System.Decimal` - which could be where the problem is coming from? perhaps?

Anyway, once saved, (after calling `Dal.SaveGridDataSet(...)`), I look up the value in the table, and it shows `1.125` (truncated) instead of `1.126` (rounded)

## Update 2

Using the Microsoft Enterprise Library (or some other OO way of accessing a database), how do I retrieve a column's precision?

Comment: Not sure what is happening under the covers there, but do you have the option to round that number yourself?  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.math.round(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: I could, but I don't know if the precision is going to be the same for each decimal column. Some have two decimal places, some 3, etc. The data type of the DataColumn is System.Decimal

Comment: Can you please show more code or specify the Class and Method you're using that does the truncation?

Comment: Yeah, I'll add relevant code momentarily. standby.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed my issue loading the whole schema on app startup, and then referencing the column information from the schema as I needed it.

Hopefully other people don't have to search as long as I did to solve this.

## Setup

```
' in whatever class you do your database communication:
Private _database As SqlDatabase
Private Shared _schema As DataTable

Sub New()
  ' or however you handle the connection string / database creation
  Dim connectionString as String = GetConnectionString()
  _database = New SqlDatabase(connectionString)

  RetrieveSchema()
End Sub


Private Function RetrieveSchema() as DataTable
  If _schema Is Nothing Then
    Using connection As SqlConnection = _database.CreateConnection()
      connection.Open()
      _schema = connection.GetSchema("Columns")
    End Using
  End If

  return _schema
End Function


Public Function GetColumnInformation(tableName As String, columnName As String) as DataRow
  Dim firstMatchingRow as DataRow = (
    From row In _schema.Rows _
    Where (
      row("TABLE_NAME") = tableName AndAlso row("COLUMN_NAME") = columnName)
    )).FirstOrDefault()

  Return firstMatchingRow
End Function
```

## Usage

```
Dim columnInformation As DataRow = Dal.GetColumnInformation(tableName, columnName)

' find the precision
Dim precision = columnInformation("NUMERIC_PRECISION")
Dim scale = columnInformation("NUMERIC_SCALE")

' convert the decimal to the column's format
' e.g.: 2.345 with a scale of 2 would result in 
'       2.35
value = Decimal.Round(value, scale)
```

Answer (score 2):

The column is declared as Decimal(5,3), so you will get 3 places of precision to the right of the decimal value, the rest will be truncated.

If you want to round the value, you have to [round](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms131274(v=vs.110).aspx) it in the datatable column before saving it to the database, or in the SQL statement being executed.

Comment: Is there a way to get the precision from the database and round to the  database's precision before saving?

Comment: You can get column information like this by running a version of "SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS", but that doesnt tell you about the SQL being executed (stored procedure's data types, etc)

Comment: Also, do you have a source? https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190476.aspx says that if you surpass the max precision, the value is truncated, so, based on what you said it could be inferred that the msdn article implies what your saying, but I don't think the msdn article is very clear.

Comment: The MSDN article says exactly what I am saying. If you surpass the max precision ( more than 3), the value is truncated.